# is site hacked ? strange home page & music displaying

Tags: magento-1.9

our site home page looking like this

[image]

is our site hacked ?  strange home page & music displaying .

but backend is working fine.

Comment: Heh, yeah. At least they're not into secretly making money from Magento egrets. Flappen zee wings and fly my little birdies!!!

Comment: The text which says "Hacked by ..." might be a bit of a giveaway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes check index.php they might have added some vulnerable code/script. Change your admin access url to something more secure and change username & password.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have, aswell as what @Khaleeq said:

You will also need to check the entire codebase for the existence of malicious code, best bet would be to download a clean copy of magento (The same version you currently have) with the same patches installed and then do a difference check against your site, using php storm or something similar.

Typically if file permissions are not locked down correctly you will find eval() code in a lot of php files, there are some legitimate uses of eval() however in my experience the majority of it would be malicious code.

You will also need to check your file and folder permissions to make sure the site is secure and check any forms you have, contact forms etc, make sure they have form keys and are secure and also make sure you have ALL the current magento patches installed

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, yes you have.

The only real way to deal with this is to employ your most recent backup.
You can manually remove the code, as mentioned in another answer, but your site has already been compromised, and we don't know to what extent.